# Issue with with a postgresql database being down

Tags: database, postgresql, deployment, psql, pgadmin

I'm new to postgres and jumped in without much research to start deploying projects with heroku. I am trying to create a database for the backend of my project and I am getting different errors when I try different solutions I have found in research. I don't know where to start or look elsewhere solutions and will try to provide as much info as I know.

Running $pg_lsclusters to see if status is down.

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

running $sudo service postgresql start.

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server                                                                                                                  * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
2021-05-06 15:56:41.113 EDT [1145] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2021-05-06 15:56:41.114 EDT [1145] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-05-06 15:56:41.114 EDT [1145] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2021-05-06 15:56:41.114 EDT [1145] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-05-06 15:56:41.114 EDT [1145] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-05-06 15:56:41.116 EDT [1145] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I have just deployed one project with out too much issue and this is a second project I am starting a new backend now if that helps.

If any more info is needed please let me know!

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

EDIT
I ran `ps -ef` and got this as a result:

```
 ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 16:41 ?        00:00:00 /init
root       239     1  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:00 /init
adamado+   240   239  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:00 sh -c "$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" 3c4e3df9e89829dce2
adamado+   241   240  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:00 sh /mnt/c/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.54
adamado+   247   241  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:00 sh /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b
adamado+   249   247  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:02 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   260   249  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:00 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   315   249  1 16:42 tty2     00:00:09 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   374   249  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:02 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   385   260  0 16:42 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
adamado+   418   374  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:02 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   425   374  4 16:42 tty2     00:00:26 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   482   425  1 16:42 tty2     00:00:05 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   602   249  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:01 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   609   249  0 16:42 tty2     00:00:02 /home/adamadolfo/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151
adamado+   629   260  0 16:42 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root       754     1  0 16:51 tty1     00:00:00 /init
adamado+   755   754  1 16:51 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
adamado+   922   755  0 16:52 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Comment: `HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?` -- try `ps -ef` and you'll probably see another postgres instance running.  Change your `postgresql.conf` to use a different port, and you'll be able to start it up

Comment: Hi and thank you @richyen for the quick response. I added an edit to the OP that is the result of running ```ps ef``` . I am trying to do some research on the postgresql.conf file to figure out what it is and how to interact with it and I am failing to figure it out. Any further advice?